# Java public class with public constructor with non-public parameter. Why?

Tags: java

Java allows to define the following pair of classes.

```
class Class1 { ... }
public Class2 { public Class2(Class1 c1) { ... } }
```

Why Class2 has public constructor if I cannot instantiate it because Class1 is not accessible?

For the record, there are no public classes that inherit from Class1.

Comment: Why is Class1 not accessible?

Comment: @anirudh Good question. I forgot to say that these classes are part from a library. Class2 is declared as a public class and Class1 is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Class1` and `Class2` are defined in same package. So they can be accessible. `Class1` has default access modifier, which is visible to all Classes inside the same package

Comment: I accept your answer but isn't it better to make Class2 constructor with default access modifier as well (e.g. remove 'public' keyword)?

Comment: @MihailSlavchev : No, It's all about the requirement. I can be or it can't be either

Comment: What could be the reason for the "requirement" to have such a public constructor when it simply can not be **used**? (That is, it can not be used by any class that could not equally use the same constructor with "default" visibility)

Answer (score 2):

At the first glance, it seems like it does not make sense: A user of this package may access Class2. But he can't create an instance of Class2, because he has no access to Class1. So there is no reason of making the constructor `public`, when the argument that it needs is not `public` as well.

The only situation where this actually makes sense is when there is another `public` class in the same package that extends Class1. Then you could create an instance of this class, and pass it to the constructor:

```
// Assuming this class extends Class1, and it is public, you 
// can create an instance of this class from outside the package:
ExtendedClass1 e = new ExtendedClass1(); 

// This is using the public constructor that expects a Class1.
// Although Class1 itself is NOT public, this constructor 
// can be called with an instance of a (public) class that
// extends Class1
Class2 c = new Class2(e);
```

But since the latter was excluded in the question, there is no reason to have this public constructor.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. I guess the library creator (the code is from ION library for android) did not do this on purpose.

Comment: @MihailSlavchev Some languages, such as C#, do not allow a class member to be more accessible than its parameter or return types. I see this as an oversight in the JLS.

Answer (score 0):

It is reasonable to have a class that limits its creation/access to members of the same package with a view that other classes in the same package will extend this class and be made public.

For example if you were implementing the Template pattern you might have super class (probably abstract) that implemented the base, shared, logic, with one or more concrete classes that implemented the the differing steps.

These concrete classes could then be instantiated by callers, but the base class wouldn't.

Arguably though the base class could equally be protected instead of package scope.

Answer (score -1):

Every class has a default constructor(if you do not provide one) you can do :

```
Class1 c1 = new Class1();
```

then

```
Class2 c2 = new Class2(c1);
```